# Multiple condition in if....else inside stored procedure

Tags: mysql, if-statement, stored-procedures

```
IF region='Mumbai' OR region='Chennai' OR region='Bangalore' OR region='Pune' region='Coimbatore' OR region='Ahmedabad' THEN
            SET region='South-west';
        ELSE
            SET region='North+East';
        END IF;
```

I am trying to create a sp i have error in the above the Condition. rest of the Stored procedure is working fine when i remove the above if condition.

i am getting the error for multiple or condition in if statement.

please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an `OR`. Try:

```
IF region='Mumbai' OR region='Chennai' OR region='Bangalore' OR region='Pune'  OR region='Coimbatore' OR region='Ahmedabad' THEN
```

Also, I think an `IN` would work here as well (I'm not 100% sure since I don't use MySQL regularly):

```
IF region IN ('Mumbai','Chennai','Bangalore','Pune','Coimbatore','Ahmedabad') THEN
```

That would be much more readable, if MySQL is happy with it.